# echo value on page posted by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to make a web page taking a number as input and searchs its name on the database,then prints name on the page (without reloading ). But I cannot update span.Ajax response returns html of the page.
the code **pra.php**

```
<php 
 if (isset($_POST['sk']))
{
$sk = $_POST['sk'];
$formatted= '\''.$sk.'\'';
$ka='SELECT itemName FROM '.$TT.' WHERE itemCode='.$formatted;
$view=odbc_exec($conn,$ka);
$Resultenter=odbc_Result($view,1);
}
?>
<form id="kod"  class="" action="" method="post">
  <input name="sk" type="text" class="form-control">
  <span><?php if($Resultenter!=null) {echo $Resultenter;}?></span>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $('input[name=sk]').change(function() {
    var skValue = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'pra.php',
      data: { sk: skValue },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log('skValue:', skValue);
 console.log('Received response:', response );
        // handle success response
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('AJAX request error:');
        console.log('Status:', status);
        console.log('Error:', error);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please share your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, be warned that your `SELECT` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: Are you calling the same page with jquery? And it reloads?

Comment: yes, it doesn't reload and I can see the value sk but doesn't update the span @OldPadawan

Comment: thanks for the warning, I trust the user, it will be used locally @NicoHaase

Comment: When Ajax performs the query, get the response value and update the div? $("#response > span").html("+skValue+"); maybe ?

Comment: There's never a good excuse to use insecure code. The user itself might not even be aware of the problem

Comment: _"I trust the user, it will be used locally"_ - It's not just about security. If your data contains, for example, a single quote `'`, your query will break (that's just one of many characters/character combos that can break your query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the innerHTML on ajax return.

Assuming the ajax response is the actual data you want to put inside the span tags, then

1. Add an ID to the span, hence, change

```
 <span><?php if($Resultenter!=null) {echo $Resultenter;}?></span>
```

to

```
 <span id=returnvalue><?php if($Resultenter!=null) {echo $Resultenter;}?></span>
```

2. Create a separate php (e.g. **pra2.php**) like

```
<php 
 if (isset($_POST['sk'])){
.... statements to retrieve the data into $Resultenter

echo $Resultenter;
}
?>
```

3. tell the system to update the span innerHTML, hence, change the block

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'pra.php',
      data: { sk: skValue },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log('skValue:', skValue);
 console.log('Received response:', response );
        // handle success response
      },
```

to

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'pra2.php',
      data: { sk: skValue },
      success: function(response) {
         document.getElementById("returnvalue").innerHTML=response;
      },
```

Last but not least, please change your query to parameterized prepared statement which is resilient against SQL injection.